# How can I remove old projects in Launch Configuration(Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, export, settings

I made a java project(using eclipse) and tried to make it as runnable jar file(export)

**Package Explorer -> right click the project -> select "Export" -> select "Runnable jar"**

Then ***export*** window is created

You may see Launch Configuration, which is list of projects.

In this list, old projects is appeared. I do not use these projects anymore, so I want to remove this projects in list(Launch Configuration)

How can I delete it?

Answer (score 2):

Open the 'Run > Run Configurations' menu. You can manage your configuration there.

If the launches are not listed there you will have to delete them manually from the workspace '.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches' directory.

Comment: could you explain it more detail? I've already seen **Run Configurations**, but I do not know how to do :(

Comment: Just use the Delete button to delete your old configurations from the list.

Comment: Oh... you misunderstood my question. I have only **2 Java Application**. However, there are 8 objects in Launch Configuration List(in export runnable jar)